# Java: Changing the image icon of a button in a loop (for a slideshow)

Tags: java, slideshow

I want to create a loop that changes the image icon of a JButton with BufferedImages stored in an ArrayList.  When I try, it simply sets it to the last image, while skipping all the rest.  The relevant code is this:

```
 private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    for (int x = 0; x < myPhotos.size(); x++) {
        icon.setImage(myPhotos.get(x));
        displayButton.setIcon(icon);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

myPhotos is an array list of buffered images.

icon is an ImageIcon

displayButton is a JButton.

I'm thinking that the problem could be that a JButton's icon can only be set once, and I'm hoping that one of you is clever enough to know how to get around this.

Comment: Don't forget to look at the JButton's API (which will link you to the AbstractButton's API). If you could only set a JButton's icon once, the API would say so, and it doesn't. Lucky for you @AKJ is "clever enough", 1+ to AKJ's answer.

Comment: I created back and forward buttons to go through the images, and the images change very slowly.  I think this actually why the slideshow was not working the way that I had expected.  Lucky for me I'm "clever enough."

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sleep here as you are blocking the painting. You should use Swing's timer for repetetive task i.e changing the icon after fixed intervals.